# Sitecore commerce 10.1 installation error 503 service is unavailable

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, sitecore-install-framework

While installing Sitecore 10.1 commerce.
I am getting attached error “HTTP 503” The Service is unavailable
The above error came while the script attempts to call

BootStrapping Commerce Services: https://commerceops.sc.com/commerceops/Bootstrap()
VERBOSE: POST https://commerceops.sc.com/commerceops/Bootstrap() with 0-byte payload

I have validated every single prerequisite and can confirm that all required pre steps are done, but still getting this error.

Can you please suggest what I am missing here

[image]

Comment: Did you follow this blog, I also got this issue then wrote this blog - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2020/09/16/errors-during-sitecore-commerce-10-installation/

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue in the `Sitecore 10` installation.
Solution - Check if the application identity user and password are correct in IIS. Check the password for your `CSFndRuntimeUser` user in `Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1` file. In my case I installed `Sitecore 9.0.2` commerce on my local as well, so I had this user already created, so I changed my password like below

The user name for a local account to be set up for the various
application pools that are created as part of the deployment.

> ```
> [string]$UserName = "CSFndRuntimeUser",
> # The password for the $UserName.
> [string]$UserPassword = "12345",
> ```

After doing the above change I `Uninstall Sitecore Commerce` and `Install` it again.

For more details follow the blog - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2020/09/16/errors-during-sitecore-commerce-10-installation/

Comment: What is the relevance of this CSFndRuntimeUser user? Does this user need other access as well? Is there any other way to use already existing identity user? I think for me this user is not getting added in logon as service group. Does the installation script do at policy level ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to ops log (~\CommerceOps\wwwroot\logs) and see what is the error causing this issue.

If you are setting in VM and getting error related to "**Login failed for user**". Then

1. Get the IP address using cmd and add IP address and system name to host file.
2. Add the account/username to “Access this computer from the network” local security policy

For more detail refer the blog:
https://sitecore-commerce.blogspot.com/2020/10/login-failed-login-is-from-untrusted.html